# Private Java Hosting with 512 or more heap size

Tags: web-hosting, tomcat

I would like to know service provider for private java hosting with 521 or more heap size with unlimited mysql databases with apache tomcat.

Edit:max $400

Comment: You can use a VPS from Amazon or Digital Ocean then you would have full control of the heap size.

Comment: But price range should be max $400

Comment: They are. $5 for DO and $15 for Amazon.

Comment: With amazon I dint get any pricing .I was talkin about $400 /year